# Replacment remote for an older garage door

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have an older Lift-A-Dor garage door opener. The remote is no longer working. The remote model# is RC-10. The garage door lift is model# LD100. Where do I purchase a replacement or is there a compatible universal remote available?

Comment: Where are you located?  US?

Comment: Just how old is this opener, anyway?

Comment: Yes in the US. The opener was purchased in the 70s. It still works good so I don't want to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase from the big box home improvement stores or online resources a device which connects to the physical button (wired) of your opener. It is a radio receiver matched with the remote(s) included in the purchase. It replaces/augments the existing system, allowing more remotes along with the original for those who have working systems.

More advanced versions will also mate with one's portable communication device with the appropriate application.

Skylink is one such brand, there are others.

Comment: Glad it's "Skylink" not "Skynet"...

Comment: Note that if this is a pre-1993 opener, it may need to be replaced, full stop, due to not having the required safety sensors (photoeyes) and intrinsic anti-crush reverse

Comment: If the garage door mechanism is working, specifically via the wall mounted button, why would replacing or facilitating a remote control require sensor installation?

Comment: I believe 3phase is pointing out the newer requirements For controllers , this and the frequency band reduction are a good reason to find a new module any brand that connects to the push button to open the door inside the garage , these modules use the latest technology so the door only opens when the remote having the same ID code programmed. But the anti crush or object in the doorway are newer features and usually require a complete new system for both.

Comment: Thank you. I will check into this also.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not find the OEM you may have problems. The frequency band with was changed a few years back and there are many different technologies for openers. There are replacement modules that the receiver is wired to the door open button with a new style transmitter this may be the best and most secure way to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To know exactly you have to know what radio frequency it uses, and the signaling technique.
You seem to know the model numbers which helps a lot.

For well known brands and models, you can do some internet searching for companies that sell this type of equipment, and have brand name or generic compatible replacements for sale.

A quick google on your info landed me on a site like this.  There are others. (disclaimer: I know nothing about this supplier)
[garage-door-opener-parts.com](https://lift-a-door.garage-door-opener-parts.com/genie_links/)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will check to see if they can help.